# SX1272 - LoRa - What is the minimal schematic (needed capacitors/resistors) to use that device?

Tags: atmega, design, schematics, datasheet, lora

I'm interested in [SX1272](http://www.semtech.com/wireless-rf/rf-transceivers/sx1272/) by Semtech. It's a LoRa modem.

I'm not the best at reading datasheets. Maybe it's because of my poor English. I wonder what is the minimum schematic of such a chip? What capacitors, resistors, inductors do I need and where?

On the Semtech's website I found something like this:
[868 MHz - Combined RFI and RFO (high efficiency PA) design, switchless](http://www.semtech.com/apps/filedown/down.php?file=SX1272MB1DCS_e343v01a_prod_folder.zip)
This PDF contains a scheme, but a lot of values of capacitors are not specified. Do I need to somehow calculate them by myself? How to do it?
Is it minimal connection needed?

I just want to connect SX1272 to ATmega88.

BTW. As I understand, the SX1272 can not be programmed? - Ie. Upload your own program? But on the other hand, what would be the use of GPIO pins?

Comment: A `LoRa` tag exists now, but not sure if there's room to add it. This is a simple, but important question.

Comment: I swapped `wireless` with `LoRa`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call that the schematic from the mBed shield minimal for the most part.
For reference:
[image]

You won't want to leave the decoupling capacitors out on the voltage rails.  As for the various inductors and capacitors on the RF antenna line, I would leave those.  Don't mess with that stuff unless you know exactly what you're doing.  I don't do RF design so I can't advise on this.

> Do I need to somehow calculate them by myself? How to do it?

The values of the components in the RF antenna path, those are very tailored to the PCB design and antenna design, it is very specialized work.  If you want to make a watered down version of the mbed shield, you can just use what the values are in the bill of materials, which is in that same zip file that contains the design files for the mbed shield, so long as you also use the same PCB design for the antenna.

> As I understand, the SX1272 can not be programmed? - Ie. Upload your
>   own program?

Right. The SX1272 is merely a modem/tranciever IC.  There is limited configuration of the GPIO pins which can be tied to do certain actions but you won't be programming it in any manner similar to an atmega.

Comment: It might be helpful to give maybe a liink to the schematic? I've had a quick search at mbed and I can't find a schematic.

Comment: @gbulmer it is the link that OP provides, 868MHz design

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I missed that file containing bill of materials.
Do you think that I can design my own PCB just following the mbed design or should I just strictly copy & paste?

Comment: @Defozo I think you could design your own PCB so long as you are familiar with the process of doing so.  If you haven't designed a trace antenna, then I would just copy/paste at least the antenna side of things.

Comment: I can't find C12, C14, C19 and C20 values. They are not mentioned in bill of materials. Moreover, what is L6 for? And why there are holes in the PCB board? What is the function of these holes?

Comment: I'm guessing you took a break from this project.  You're referring to the vias all over the board?  The area where they are high density near the antenna is called a "via fence".  Most of the vias on this board are  for EMI reasons to catch emitted interference.  

As for the capacitors and inductor, those are for impedance matching.  It is a critical aspect of antenna design and the implementation of it varies wildly by the design of the PCB.  It may be that they were left off the BOM for that reason, I'm not sure though.  Looks like you're s.o.l. unless you're going to learn antenna design.